# Android Var Naming Conventions - What's the best way? (Besides using "m" and "s")

Tags: android, variables, naming-conventions

My application is getting quite big. I was not disciplined in my naming of variables/methods and it's come back to bite me.

I have now read through Google's naming conventions for Android. In this document it speaks mostly of code structure and of course mentions using "m" for a method variable, "s" for a static variable and nothing for a public variable. While this is good, I want to take this methodology further and apply a methodology to the actual variable and method names.

Does anyone have a nice succint system for naming variables and methods? What works best for clarity? What should be avoided? I find consistency is paramount, and having a good system which you can easily remember will help make my code consistent and more readable.

I appreciate it!

Comment: If you work in Eclipse any other modern IDE (I don't believe you work in a plain text editor) why do you need those "m" and "s"? You have an IDE that highlights instance members in different color, changes font for static members, etc. I'd simply suggest not to use "m" and "s" in order not to pollute the code with those and not to waste your time.

Comment: Well Google requires their naming convention if you want to submit code to them. One day I might do this, so I was intending on learning their conventions now.

Any suggestions on how to name your variables and functions? What works good for you?

Comment: So, no tips on how you name variables? Could someone point me to some guidance? Thanks!